# UPDATE - Hookless wheels: tube type tires compatibility

Tags: tubeless

I have hookless wheels (Giant SLR0) and I’m searching for a new set of tires. While I know that there’s a very limited compatibility list for tubeless tires, are there any considerations for tube type tires compatibility with hookless wheels? I would like to mount Continental 5000 tube types.

For SLR wheel owners: **check Model Year**. Only Giant SLR wheels starting from MY 2021 are hookless, all previous production is non-hookless (like mine MY 2019) so not to be considered in the present thread.

Comment: Since the original post, I came across an authoritative opinion which overturns the the accepted answer. This article [link](https://www.cyclingweekly.com/reviews/wheels/giant-slr-1-disc-full-carbon-42-wheels) cites a UK Giant representative saying:
_"However (and from personal experience; my own and colleagues) the Giant SLR 1 Disc Full Carbon 42 wheels do work exceptionally well with conventional clincher tyres. We have used all carbon rim profiles extensively with Vittoria, Conti, Schwalbe in various widths up to and including Conti 28s/Vittoria 28s._

Comment: Conti released the GP5000 S TR yesterday designed to work with hookless rims.  Giant didnt update their website yet, but i'd be very surprised if they weren't added to the list soon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Continental requires hooked rims even for their *tubeless* 5000s.

The tire/rim interface is different for tubeless setups and tubed setups. With tubed setups, the bead locks against the hook. With tubeless, the bead is supposed to be tight against the rim bed; the hook (if present) is there as a backup.

What you're proposing is using a tire that was designed to lock against a hook, without any hook. This sounds like an invitation to rim blowoff. I would be surprised if any tire manufacturer endorsed the use of tubed tires on hookless rims.

Comment: I'd be surprised if there was anything wrong with a tubeless tire designed for hookless rims and putting a tube in there. In fact, this is the backup strategy for many tubeless cyclists: if there's a puncture the sealant won't seal, put a tube in.

Comment: Vittoria may also be incompatible with hookless rims. There are probably some other manufacturers. The standards are still settling down. There is an unconfirmed rumor about a new incoming Conti GP5000 version, and I wouldn't be surprised if this one is hookless compatible.

Comment: @juhist I agree, but that's not the scenario under consideration. The OP wants to use tube-type Conti 5000s on a hookless rim.

Comment: Here a comprehensive explanation of the Giant hookless technology along with a list of compatible models:
https://www.giant-bicycles.com/global/hookless-technology

Comment: I might suggest modifying the last sentence just for clarity: nobody would authorize non-tubeless clincher tires for use on hookless rims. “Tubed tires” might be read as disallowing a tubeless clincher tire with a tube inside. That is definitely not the case, otherwise how would you get home if your sealant doesn’t work?

Comment: As of yesterday, the opening line of this answer needs a small modification - Conti have just released the GP5000 S TR which is now hookless compatible

Comment: @WeiwenNg as far as how you get home for when your sealant doesn't work, I'm not saying you aren't wrong, but not every product is made for every instance. It's entirely possible that a product designed for racing would expect that you would just do a wheel swap and putting a tube in there is just something that would never happen.  It's kind of like the question of how do you fix hydraulic brakes on the road. For the most part, you can't, unless you carry a lot of gear and spares. With mechaical brakes you could just carry an extra cable and fix most issues on the road.